# Мне нужно расшифровать хэш phpbb которое просолено

Tags: хеширование, md5, phpbb

Мне нужно расшифровать хэш phpbb, пример: $H$9Fvycw/wICt.NknBl7C2ut2G5l0QYU1
я так понял $H$ это байт ,9 кол-во , Fvycw/wI случайная соль получается остаток md5? можете помочь пожалуйста

Comment: Соление для того и существует, чтобы «расшифровать» было невозможно